# Adding XML elements in the right order

Tags: c#, xsd

I want to add elements to the [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object and the order of the elements for that XML I want to build is defined in a XSD e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Recipient"/>
        <xs:element name="City"/>
     </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Now I want to add the following two XElements

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Address"));
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("City"));
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("Recipient"));
```

Can does XDocument automatically bring the elements into the right order by reference to the xsd? So if I write the XDocument to string the element Recipient should written first and then the element City.

Comment: XSD is way to provide specification on how your XML should look...It is not going to automatically arrange XML referring XSD....you can validate your XML using XSD but not automatically correct it

Comment: I know that XSD providing the specification how the XML should look like. Therefor the order of the nodes in the XSD matters during the validation process. And that's why I can imagine it should be possible to arrange a sequence of elements automatically if I build the XML against a XSD file. Because XDocument could know that order while the the nodes are added.

Comment: No still not possible consider scenario where child nodes with same same name appears in more than one parent..so when you add child element how would Xdocument know under which parent node it should go

Comment: I cant unstand it, because the path should be clear if I want to add a element. If I want to add it twice with different parents I have to particularize the path for both parents.