# Putting xml elements in order by given xsd using xslt

Tags: xslt, xsd

I build a simple xml document e.g.

```
<Address>
   <Recipient>
     abc
   </Recipient>
   <Street>
     123
   </Street>
</Address>
```

For this xml there exists an xsd e.g.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Street"/>
        <xs:element name="Recipient"/>
     </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

as you can see the order of Street and Recipient is wrong. How to reorder the xml with respect to the xsd or detect the order during the building process of the xml?

Comment: How is this question related to [this previous question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35330636/1987598)? What exactly is your "building process"? XML validation does not transform documents, it will only tell you if a document is valid or not and will do nothing beyond that. If you meant to ask for an XSLT stylesheet that does this: how extensive are the reordering rules? Are they known or would an XSLT stylesheet need to infer the rules from an XSD?

Comment: I create the XML from set of strings where each string looks like a path. From the path I create a element and add it to my document. But the order of my elements is defined in the xsd and I am looking for smart way to feed my building process with that information regardless whether I am using c# or xslt.

Comment: You could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119292/how-to-transform-unordered-elements-in-xml-to-match-an-xsdsequence-order/ which has an answer, but also has an answer from Michael Kay (whose opinion is worth listening to) about why this approach is misguided.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:variable name="schema">
        <xsl:copy-of select="doc('test.xsd')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Address">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="Address" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$schema//xs:element[@name='Address']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element/@name">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$Address/*[local-name()=current()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this solution is restricted to this rather simple case only.